# Cartesian product in SSIS

Tags: ssis, bids, cartesian-product

I have two tables(**Table1** and **Table2**) in a SQL Server database and I need to create a third table (**Table3**) that contains all the columns from the two tables and of course their data. Each row of **Table1** is associated with each row of **Table2**.

This operation is a cartesian product but apparently it is not available in SSIS. May anybody know how to do it?

I read in the Internet that using the cartesian product is not a good practice in terms of performance but **Table2** has just one row, meaning that **Table3** will have as many rows as **Table1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link where there are explained two methods to obtain a **cartesian product** by using **SSIS**:

http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/performing-a-cross-join-cartesian-product-in-ssis/